# How to start GPCLK2 pin inside code of C/C++

Tags: pi-4, c++

I would like to use GPIO 6 (GPCLK2) to produce a 8.192 MHz clock in other words i would like to use its alternate function of a general purpose clock, but im having trouble looking for a guide that does it inside the code. Im using C++ to write my code, and doing it in code assures the clock is activated before any functions will be executed that relies on it. It also makes the project cleaner as i only need to execute a single file.

Can anyone teach me how to do this? I am using the raspberry pi

I have tried to strip joan's [minimal_clk.c](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_minimal_clk) and [minimal_gpio.c](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_minimal_gpio) to what i need only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static volatile uint32_t piPeriphBase = 0x20000000;

static volatile int pi_is_2711 = 0;

#define SYST_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x003000)
#define DMA_BASE   (piPeriphBase + 0x007000)
#define CLK_BASE   (piPeriphBase + 0x101000)
#define GPIO_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x200000)
#define UART0_BASE (piPeriphBase + 0x201000)
#define PCM_BASE   (piPeriphBase + 0x203000)
#define SPI0_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x204000)
#define I2C0_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x205000)
#define PWM_BASE   (piPeriphBase + 0x20C000)
#define BSCS_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x214000)
#define UART1_BASE (piPeriphBase + 0x215000)
#define I2C1_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x804000)
#define I2C2_BASE  (piPeriphBase + 0x805000)
#define DMA15_BASE (piPeriphBase + 0xE05000)

#define DMA_LEN   0x1000 /* allow access to all channels */
#define CLK_LEN   0xA8
#define GPIO_LEN  0xF4
#define SYST_LEN  0x1C
#define PCM_LEN   0x24
#define PWM_LEN   0x28
#define I2C_LEN   0x1C
#define BSCS_LEN  0x40

#define GPSET0 7
#define GPSET1 8

#define GPCLR0 10
#define GPCLR1 11

#define GPLEV0 13
#define GPLEV1 14

#define GPPUD     37
#define GPPUDCLK0 38
#define GPPUDCLK1 39

/* BCM2711 has different pulls */

#define GPPUPPDN0 57
#define GPPUPPDN1 58
#define GPPUPPDN2 59
#define GPPUPPDN3 60

#define SYST_CS  0
#define SYST_CLO 1
#define SYST_CHI 2

static volatile uint32_t  *gpioReg = MAP_FAILED;
static volatile uint32_t  *systReg = MAP_FAILED;
static volatile uint32_t  *bscsReg = MAP_FAILED;

#define PI_BANK (gpio>>5)
#define PI_BIT  (1<<(gpio&0x1F))


#define CLK_GP2_CTL 32
#define CLK_GP2_DIV 33

#define CLK_PASSWD  (0x5A<<24)

#define CLK_CTL_MASH(x)((x)<<9)
#define CLK_CTL_BUSY    (1 <<7)
#define CLK_CTL_KILL    (1 <<5)
#define CLK_CTL_ENAB    (1 <<4)
#define CLK_CTL_SRC(x) ((x)<<0)

#define CLK_DIV_DIVI(x) ((x)<<12)
#define CLK_DIV_DIVF(x) ((x)<< 0)

#define CLK_CTL_SRC_OSC  1  /* 19.2 MHz */
#define CLK_CTL_SRC_PLLC 5  /* 1000 MHz */
#define CLK_CTL_SRC_PLLD 6  /*  500 MHz */
#define CLK_CTL_SRC_HDMI 7  /*  216 MHz */

static volatile uint32_t  *clkReg  = MAP_FAILED;

/* gpio modes. */

#define PI_INPUT  0
#define PI_OUTPUT 1
#define PI_ALT0   4
#define PI_ALT1   5
#define PI_ALT2   6
#define PI_ALT3   7
#define PI_ALT4   3
#define PI_ALT5   2

unsigned gpioHardwareRevision(void)
{
   static unsigned rev = 0;

   FILE *filp;
   char buf[512];
   char term;
   int chars=4; /* number of chars in revision string */

   filp = fopen ("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");

   if (filp != NULL)
   {
      while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), filp) != NULL)
      {
         if (!strncasecmp("revision", buf, 8))
         {
            if (sscanf(buf+strlen(buf)-(chars+1),
               "%x%c", &rev, &term) == 2)
            {
               if (term != '\n') rev = 0;
               else rev &= 0xFFFFFF; /* mask out warranty bit */
            }
         }
      }

      fclose(filp);
   }

   if (filp = fopen("/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges" , "rb"))
   {
      if (fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), filp) >= 8)
      {
         piPeriphBase = buf[4]<<24 | buf[5]<<16 | buf[6]<<8 | buf[7];
         if (!piPeriphBase)
            piPeriphBase = buf[8]<<24 | buf[9]<<16 | buf[10]<<8 | buf[11];

         if (piPeriphBase == 0xFE00000) pi_is_2711 = 1;
      }
      fclose(filp);
   }

   return rev;
}


static uint32_t * initMapMem(int fd, uint32_t addr, uint32_t len)
{
    return (uint32_t *) mmap(0, len,
       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
       MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED,
       fd, addr);
}


int gpioInitialise(void)
{
   int fd;

   gpioHardwareRevision(); /* sets rev and peripherals base address */

   fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ;

   if (fd < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,
         "This program needs root privileges.  Try using sudo\n");
      return -1;
   }

   gpioReg  = initMapMem(fd, GPIO_BASE,  GPIO_LEN);
   systReg  = initMapMem(fd, SYST_BASE,  SYST_LEN);
   bscsReg  = initMapMem(fd, BSCS_BASE,  BSCS_LEN);

   close(fd);

   if ((gpioReg == MAP_FAILED) ||
       (systReg == MAP_FAILED) ||
       (bscsReg == MAP_FAILED))
   {
      fprintf(stderr,
         "Bad, mmap failed\n");
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}

void gpioSetMode(unsigned gpio, unsigned mode)
{
   int reg, shift;

   reg   =  gpio/10;
   shift = (gpio%10) * 3;

   gpioReg[reg] = (gpioReg[reg] & ~(7<<shift)) | (mode<<shift);
}

static int initClock2(int divI, int divF, int MASH)
{
   clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] = CLK_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_KILL;

   /* wait for clock to stop */
   while (clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] & CLK_CTL_BUSY)
      usleep(10);

   clkReg[CLK_GP2_DIV] =
      (CLK_PASSWD | CLK_DIV_DIVI(divI) | CLK_DIV_DIVF(divF));

   usleep(10);

   clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] =
      (CLK_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_MASH(MASH) | CLK_CTL_SRC(CLK_CTL_SRC_OSC));

   usleep(10);

   clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] |= (CLK_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_ENAB);
}

static int termClock2()
{
   clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] = CLK_PASSWD | CLK_CTL_KILL;

   /* wait for clock to stop */

   while (clkReg[CLK_GP2_CTL] & CLK_CTL_BUSY)
      usleep(10);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Stage1\n");
    if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 1;
    printf("Stage2\n");
    initClock2(61,144,0);               //Segmentation Fault here
    printf("Stage3\n");
    gpioSetMode(6, PI_ALT0);
    printf("Stage4\n");
    usleep(10000);
    printf("Stage5\n");
    termClock2();                       //Segmentation Fault here
    printf("Stage6\n");
    gpioSetMode(6, PI_INPUT);
}
```

I get segmentation fault i think the problem is clkReg being not quite right i guess(wrong address? or has new name).

Im using a raspberry pi 4 and an external logic analyzer to check if the pins are outputting the signal

Comment: What Raspberry Pi do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but if you are using the pi4 it has a different peripheral base address which for the pi 4 is 0xFE000000. You also seem to forget to map the clock register, check your gpioInitilise() inside you will see

```
gpioReg  = initMapMem(fd, GPIO_BASE,  GPIO_LEN);
systReg  = initMapMem(fd, SYST_BASE,  SYST_LEN);
bscsReg  = initMapMem(fd, BSCS_BASE,  BSCS_LEN);
```

add the line for clock reg

```
clkReg = initMapMem(fd, CLK_BASE,  CLK_LEN);
```

Youre code can still be further stripped down skipping all the checks, if you are only going to run it on the pi 4

Comment: This actually worked for me ! although you did not provide the full code snippet it greatly helped me made mine to work so im giving you the points. Thank you ! I  can see where i can still strip down the code to further reduce it down

Answer (score 1):

I have some code to set the clocks [here](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_minimal_clk).

It will need modifications for recent model Pi's to account for the new peripheral base addresses.

However it will show you what you need to know.

Comment: I do only have the model 4 with me, I saw a comment of yours in the raspberry pi forum wherein you said that only the periphiral base address is changed and the offsets are the same. So i changed the base address to "0xFE000000" and try to execute the c file by `gcc -o program minimal_clk.c` followed by `./program`. and there seems to be nothing happening when i execute it. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have a look in http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_minimal_gpio which was updated.

Comment: I was somehow able to manage make it run [image](https://ibb.co/GFg9CQ2) but how do i set it to output on GPIO6 (GPCLK2) or is the code ment to output on all clocks? My probe is on GPIO6 and there is currently no signal there and the voltage is steady at 1.84v

Comment: *steady 3.2v not 1.84v

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: I have modified your minimal_clk.c to the registers of minimal_gpio (the pi4 compatible). The [code is long](https://codeshare.io/5zN7rW). ill maybe add it after i will be able to trim it to be a bit shorter

Comment: I got a bit deeper on how your minimal_clk.c code works and the function that would do what i need seems to be `static int initClock(int clock, int source, int divI, int divF, int MASH)` what does the I and F stand for in the `divX` parameter? and what does the last parameter `mash` do?

Comment: Ignore mash.  I is integer and F is the fractional part of the clock divider.

Comment: How do i get those values for I and F ? Mash is being ORed in clk_gp2_ctl, can i just remove it from being ORed ? If not what value should i defaulty set it to ?

Comment: Hi good sir when i tried to run it i get a segmentation fault on both `initClock2` an `termClock` am i missing something?

Comment: the arguments i used are `initClock2(61,144,0);`

Answer (score 1):

I would start by finding or making a tool which lets you read and write system memory from the command line, such as [`busybox devmem`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_27_2/miscutils/devmem.c). Then you could experiment without re-compiling your program every time, and see the outcome of each step in isolation. Start by trying out:

```
sudo apt-get install busybox
sudo busybox devmem 0xFE000000
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try to build `busybox` (or just `devmem`) from sources.

Comment: I tried installing it and running the commands you have said. I got a response of 0x00000000 would that be correct? i check my logic analyzer and none of the clock pins are outputting a clock signal.

Comment: @DrakeJest That command is to test that `busybox` is working. Obvioulsy, reading from a random address is unlikely to activate the clock. You'll probably have to write certain values to certain addresses. I just find it easier to read/write config registers live than change/compile/run a C program every time.

Comment: Although this will be a useful tool later on my current problem is what to write and where to write, sadly i dont have much know how to how embeds systems work.